# Show Custom Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal which is not hidden. I mean there is no fade class which is generally seen as `<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">`. I want to show modal as popup when user clicks on button. The code below does not work as it is unable to detect it as modal.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('.custom-modal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mymodal = $('#myModal');
    mymodal.modal('show');
    
  });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg custom-modal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you still need `class="modal"`, also the id should be on the same element, rtm https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version per the instructions in the twitter-bootstrap tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You just need to add `class="modal fade"` with `id="myModal"` and it will work perfectly.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/2qfeagc5/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.custom-modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mymodal = $('#myModal');
    mymodal.modal('show');

  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg custom-modal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have written in the first line that I can't use <div class="modal fade" role="dialog">